# node.js require("mongodb") throws an exception

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a newbie to `node.js` (but 10 years experience with C#)
I have the following code

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var path = require('path');
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require("express");
var mongo = require("./node_modules/mongo");
var Server = mongo.Server;
var Db = mongo.Db;
var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
var db = new Db('mydb', server);
```

I get this exception:

> Error: Cannot find module './node_modules/mongo'
>
> ```
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
> ```

I also tried:

```
var mongo = require("mongo");
```

Comment: Did you `npm install mongodb` to get the driver?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
```